# Ubuntu 22.04 shows "RETBleed: WARNING: Spectre v2 ..." message at startup

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, security

In many hosts through `VirtualBox` **6.1.38**, for many Virtual Machines: `Ubuntu` *Desktop/Servers* was accomplished an upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04. The process was successful.

Now for all the *Desktop* environments (not sure if happens for *servers*) when Ubuntu is loading appears this message:

```
RETBleed: WARNING: Spectre v2 mitigation leaves CPU vulnerable to RETBleed attacks, data leaks possible!
```

This message **only** has appeared for this `22.04` version - therefore **never** for previous releases such as `18.04` to `20.04`

My concern is:

- Is it a direct bug about security of Ubuntu itself? - or
- Is it "something" caused by VirtualBox?

How to fix this situation?

**Note** I can work in peace through all these Virtual Machines.

Comment: it also shows on hosted `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` (also on Virtual Box `7`)

Comment: Perhaps happens the same on `Virtual Box` **6.1.40** too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible answer at *VirtualBox forums*: [RETBleed attack warning](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=107103).

Execute this:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --spec-ctrl on
```

Comment: please add details to the concequances

Answer (score 0):

I’m not an expert in answering this but, this happened to me. I disconnected my external HDD and rebooted the pc and it worked fine.

Comment: Not really helpful. I guess it just did boot faster, so you could not see the message